# Weblogic : How to push weblogic domain libraries to remote managed servers in a cluster using wlst

Tags: weblogic, wlst

Using wlst how do I copy the jars from `<DOMAIN_HOME>/lib` directory to remote managed server's `<DOMAIN_HOME>/lib` directory

Comment: I don't think you can do it with WLST. However you can call System commands to copy the files in question.